# access markup of InAppBrowser in ionic app

Tags: ionic-framework, inappbrowser

I am developing an ionic app and using InAppBrowser. I am redirecting user to perform some authentication/authorization kind of thing which has two screen.

1. Login screen
2. Token screen

When user successfully login then token is generated in inAppBrowser.

Now I want this token in my ionic app. Can you please give me any hint which help me to solve this

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it by **loadstop**

```
           const browser = this.iab.create(Your_URL, '_blank', options);

            browser.on("loadstop").subscribe((event: InAppBrowserEvent) => {
                    console.log("Check event Data :", event)
                    let url = event.url;
                    if (event.type == "loadstop") {
                       // handle token
                    }


            }, (error) => {
                console.log('some error came up', error)
                reject(error);
            })
```

Comment: I have tried it but when using _blank as target a white screen appears only